# Unknown behavior when using react useState and useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I have this code :

```
function Parent(props) {

    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [itemArr, setItemArr] = useState([]);
    const [reRender, setReRender] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        let _items = items.slice(0).reverse().map((item, idx) => {
            return {
                type: {
                    subject: item.type,
                    type: "text"
                },
                child: {
                    subject: <Child
                                data = {item}
                             ></Child>,
                    type: "inline"
                },
            }
        });

        setItemArr(_items);
    }, [reRender])

    function newItem(info) {

        let [date, time] = getDate();

        let tmp = items;
        tmp.push({
            id: items.length,
            type: info.type,
            date: date,
            time: time
        });
        
        setItems(tmp);
        setReRender(!reRender);
    }

    return (
            <MyTable
                 items = {itemArr}
            ></MyTable>
    )
}
```

and my `Child` component:

```js
export default function ScanTimer(props) {

    console.log(props.data);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(props.data);
    }, []);

    return(
        <div></div>
    )
}
```

when I run my app, and add two item to the table, first `console.log` in child component (the one that is out of `useEffect`) shows right data. but last one (in `useEffect`) shows wrong data (the data that is for first item inserted into table).

it happens also when I init a state In this way:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(props.data);
```

in the Child element.

I don't know why it happens. can somebody help me??

Comment: You've set the logging `useEffect` up to only run on the first render. Did you want it to run on every render?

Comment: I think I could not explain my problem well. I know when useEffect fires. Here I have a table that each item that has a component named `Child`. so each item added to table has a `Child` component in itself. well, my problem is, each time I add an item to the table, it must log its own data passed to it. but all of them log data of the first item added to the table.

I hope I could explain it better

Answer (score 0):

> first console.log in child component (the one that is out of useEffect) shows right data

That runs every time the component is rendered. It will always show the latest data.

> but last one (in useEffect) shows wrong data (the data that is for first item inserted into table

The runs every time the dependency list changes.

So it runs on the first render (with the first value) because the dependencies have changed from "didn't exist" to "exists".

Then on subsequent renders, since there are no dependancies in the list (you passed an empty array), they haven't changed, so it doesn't run.

**That is the point of `useEffect`**.

If you want it to run when the data changes, you have to include that in the dependency list.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.data);
}, [props.data]);
```

Comment: I think I could not explain my problem well. I know when useEffect fires. Here I have a table that each item that has a component named `Child`. so each item added to table has a `Child` component in itself. well, my problem is, each time I add an item to the table, it must log its own data passed to it. but all of them log data of the first item added to the table.

I hope I could explain it better